# Flash message is not set after redirect

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to set a flash message, which is working fine if I render a template within the method, like this:

```
return $this->render('login/forgotten_password.html.twig', [
    'form' => $form->createView(),
]);
```

However, if I return a `RedirectResponse` the flash message is not being set, even if I redirect to the exact same method:

```
return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('forgotten_password', []));
```

How come this is not working, and how do I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of symfony are you using?

We are running on 2.6.1 and it works if you set it like this before the redirection:

```
$request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add("success", "Test");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work from your controller

```
$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('info', 'Test');
```

Answer (score -1):

Use sessions for flash message display.

And make session unset after it produce output, and also write javascript which hides flashmessage div.

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['SUCCESS']) && !empty($_SESSION['SUCCESS'])){
    if($_SESSION['SUCCESS']=='TRUE'){
        $alert_class = 'alert-success';
    }else{
        $alert_class = 'alert-danger';
    }
    ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="alert <?php echo $alert_class?>" role="alert">
                <?php
                if(isset($_SESSION['MESSAGE']) && !empty($_SESSION['MESSAGE'])){
                    echo $_SESSION['MESSAGE'];
                }
                unset($_SESSION['SUCCESS']);
                unset($_SESSION['MESSAGE']);
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

**jQuery to hide flash message**

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.alert').each(function () {
       if($(this).attr('role')=='alert'){
           $(this).fadeOut();
       }
    });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: This is pretty far from what I need, the question is aimed at Symfony, not vanilla PHP

Comment: sorry, for symfony i don't have answer.

Comment: may be this will help you. http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html OR http://www.craftitonline.com/2011/07/symfony2-setting-flash-messages/